# Cannot define anything in publishing block of build.gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

I'm trying to create a library and publish it to maven local. When I start trying to add a `MavenPublication` to `publications`, the IDE gives it a dotted underline like it's an unresolved reference. Same with parameters like `from` and `artifact`.

If I uncomment the `pom` block, gradle sync fails and says `Cause: invalid type code: B3`, ultimately because of `org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException` on one of the parameters within.

[image: IntelliJ Idea screen shot]

This build.gradle file is in one of my modules. The top level build.gradle is pretty simple.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "idea"

    group = 'com.mygroup'
    version = '1.0.0'

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}
```

And here's the module's build.gradle.

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'signing'
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.allJava
    archiveClassifier = 'sources'
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar) {
    from javadoc
    archiveClassifier = 'javadoc'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId = 'mylibrary'
            from components.java
            artifact sourcesJar
            artifact javadocJar
            pom {
                name = 'MyLibrary'
                organization {
                    name 'MyOrg'
                    url 'www.myurl.com'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

signing {
    sign publishing.publications.mavenJava
}

javadoc {
    if(JavaVersion.current().isJava9Compatible()) {
        options.addBooleanOption('html5', true)
    }
}
```

I'm using Gradle 5.1.1, IntelliJ Idea 2019.1.2, and JDK 12.0.1.

Comment: Does Gradle build from command line work? Try using latest 5.2 Gradle version. Seems that such DSL is not supported for 5.1 version.

Comment: I just tried 5.2.1 and 5.4.1 and they all have the same issues.

Comment: Can you please post the module's `build.gradle` with `pom` block? Otherwise, I have to add my own, specifically from [the official Gradle doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:complete_example). And it works just fine with your `build.gradle` scripts. With regards to the dotted underlines, it's a problem with IntelliJ support for Gradle build scripts written in Groovy

Comment: And which version of Java/IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: IntelliJ Idea 2019.1.2 and JDK 12.0.1. And in the process of coming up with a minimal `pom` block to make it fail above, I think I found the issue, because if I add `=` signs, it completes the sync without errors. Why are equal signs necessary here, but not in a `plugins` block where you have lines like `id 'maven-publish'?

Comment: Glad to hear that you could find a solution for the original issue! Could you please clarify which question you’d like to see answered here (maybe this one: “Why are equal signs necessary here, but not in a plugins block where you have lines like `id 'maven-publish'?”)? Thanks :-)

Comment: @Chriki My follow-up question was about the syntax confusion and Dmitry helped with that, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's a bit long explanation, let me clarify the situation here instead of replying in the comments to my question about providing the complete example with a `pom`-offender block. As the OP has already figured out, the problem is in the missing `=` sign. It's necessary for `pom.organization` and must not be present in the `plugin.id`.

For `plugins` block, it's a well-known [Groovy convention of method call](http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_omitting_parentheses), which allow us to omit parentheses. And you can't use assignment here because `id` is not a property of a class. Look at the Gradle source code for [plugins block](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/55c6a0996ca3816cd7060936747b3fa05c59cb84/subprojects/core-api/src/main/java/org/gradle/plugin/use/PluginDependenciesSpec.java#L114).

However, if we look at [pom.organization block](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/55c6a0996ca3816cd7060936747b3fa05c59cb84/subprojects/maven/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/publish/maven/MavenPom.java#L98) we see the receiver of [Action](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/55c6a0996ca3816cd7060936747b3fa05c59cb84/subprojects/base-services/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/Action.java#L24) is [MavenPomOrganization](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/55c6a0996ca3816cd7060936747b3fa05c59cb84/subprojects/maven/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/publish/maven/MavenPomOrganization.java#L29) which has `getName()` and `getUrl()` returning `Property<String>` and not taking any arguments. From bare Groovy standpoint, it's definitely not the case of omitting parentheses. But I don't know for sure how the assignment syntax (`name = 'MyOrg'`) works here under the hood. At first glance I can just speculate that it's some sort of Gradle magic using Groovy magic, e.g. AST transformation or something

Comment: Are the dotted underlines in Idea a bug in their Groovy parser?

Comment: @Tenfour04 IntelliJ has not been "fixing" this kind of problems for many years now.  It's sort of a pain point for all Gradle users. The reason behind this is the dynamic nature of Groovy which is powerful but not so easy to support in IDE. As a result of not supporting the Gradle Groovy DSL in IntelliJ, the Gradle team decided to move to Kotlin DSL which is "surprisingly" is a child of JetBrains and it's a statically compiled language with powerful features taken from many existing languages. Of course, we can raise this issue with JB team but I'm sure it won't be fixed